# Can we assign string functions Like(Patindex,charindex) along with select command to a dynamic sql variable?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Can we  assign string functions Like(Patindex,charindex) along with select command to a dynamic sql variable ?

here is an example that i want assign to a dynamic sql varaible

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Dynamic_SP
      @Table_Name sysname
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000)
      SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT patindex('%,%',ColumnName) FROM  '+ @Table_Name
      EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
END
GO

EXEC Dynamic_SP 'tblFilm'
```

i konow it will raise an error at assigning query to the @DynamicSQL ! But is there any way i can do ??

Comment: You also need to wrap your table name with QUOTENAME to help minimize the risk of sql injection.

Comment: Thanks i'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Dynamic_SP
      @Table_Name sysname
      @ColumnName  sysname
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000)
      SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT patindex(''%,%'',' + @ColumnName + ') FROM  '+ @Table_Name
     -- PRINT (@DynamicSQL)   --comment in this and comment out the EXEC(@DynamicSQL) to check whether the query looks good
      EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
END
GO
```

Comment: you did not include the `@parameter` in your dynamic query, there is no need to use `sp_executesql`

Comment: glad to know that ;)

Comment: Execuse LONG I have one more quetsion that can i pass Columnname as parameter in that select statement??

Comment: I got it LONG No Problem

Comment: @sivareddy , updated, take a look and you could replace any part with parameters using string concatenation :)